# Should I synchronize notifyObservers calls?

Tags: java, multithreading, observable, observer-pattern, synchronized

I've found this implementation of Observable:

```
public class ObservableObject extends Observable {
    private static ObservableObject instance = new ObservableObject();

    public static ObservableObject getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private ObservableObject() {
    }

    public void updateValue(Object data) {
        synchronized (this) {
            // The call to setChanged marks this Observable object as having been changed; the hasChanged method will now return true.
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(data);
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to understand is what is the difference between the [default implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Observable.java#132) use of synchronized block and the use of synchronized block at the code I found above, is there a need for both?, is there a better(correct) way?

Comment: I believe there's no difference other than locking the same object twice, since the default implementation uses the Observable instance to acquire the lock and your class `ObservableObject` is a subclass of `Observable`, in both instances the current `ObservableObject` instance will be locked

Comment: @ManZzup Default implementation locks data where as the given implementation locks on itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't call notifyObservers with the lock held. The posted code is defective for reasons cited in the linked code's comments:

> We don't want the Observer doing callbacks into arbitrary code while holding its own Monitor. The code where we extract each Observable from the Vector and store the state of the Observer needs synchronization, but notifying observers does not (should not).  The worst result of any potential race-condition here is that:
>
> 1) a newly-added Observer will miss a notification in progress
>
> 2) a recently unregistered Observer will be wrongly notified when it doesn't care

The method notifyObservers includes the calls to update the observers which the java.util.Observable code was careful to leave unsynchronized. If the observable holds its own lock while updating observers, where the observable doesn't have control of what the observers do, there's no telling how long the lock could be held for, impacting the responsiveness of the observable.

Comment: Thanks, you explanation helped.